# Laravel 5.2 4 rolle

Tags: laravel, authentication

I need help how to make laravel 5.2 authenticate with 4 rolls?

1. guest
2. registered
3. support
4. admin

I make something but every time I get

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','isAdmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return view('admin');
    });
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','isSupport']], function () {
    Route::get('/support', function(){
        return view('support');
    });
});
```

**Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->role == '3') {
        return $next($request);
    }
    if(Auth::guest()){
        redirect('login');
    }else
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with code snippets.

Comment: @jacurtis this is my code

Answer (score 2):

If I assume, you add `isAdmin` middleware to path `/`. `isAdmin` middleware is checking that user have a proper role (role with `id === 3`). If not, then redirect to `/`.

So only user with role 3 can access to path `/` but system still try redirect to this path. Infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @grzegorz has the correct answer already posted on here I believe. But I will try to explain it clearly.

So in your route for the root of your application ('/') you tell Laravel to process middleware to authenticate users. This in and of itself is not unusual. The middleware runs a function to see if a user basically has level 3 authority and if they do then you return the request url (which is also '/' and the process continues in an infinite loop, because they are sent to the '/' url, then it processes and returns the same url again, causing it to process middleware again, going forever. This is why you are getting an error saying that there are `too many redirects`, because it redirects a whole bunch of times with no end in sight and eventually Laravel stops it for you and returns an error.

## How to fix this problem?

Easy, you have a good start already. But what I would do is that when you check to see if a user has auth level 3 and they do, then simply return `true`. There is no need to return the requesting url, because this is middleware, so its running when someone requests a URL. So the purpose of your middleware would be to return `true` meaning "don't do anything, just continue". Then if the user **does not** have authority level 3, then you would want to redirect them away from this page. **Do an actual redirect though** (as opposed to returning a url string like you are now). So you would want to do something like this:

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

*You could also add some flash data to this with an error message to display to the user something telling them that they do not have access to this route.*

#### Last note:

It would be strange to only allow high level authority users to be the only ones that can access a homepage. Maybe this is what you want, but it seems weird so I wanted to mention it in case it is unintended. What I wonder you are doing is maybe trying to display different information on the homepage depending if someone is logged in or not. if this is the case, then you don't want to use middleware, you want to move this to the controller and then conditionally add html for logged in users or something like that.